# Reduce Phonegap project size (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I've just started looking at Phonegap since I'm quite good with web developement, but I'm not confident with Android developement (neither with Eclipse), so I need your help to define a "basic starter" empty project to start developing from. 
Here is attached my "example" folder: [LINK](https://mega.co.nz/#F!DUQ0zDCb!OtOklWx-Arx9xYRJYMpYTA) (Mega)
Can you teach me which files/folders can be deleted, and explain what is their content)?

Thank you very much!
Andy W.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the documentation?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Answer (score 0):

Check out this official tutorial: [Getting Started with Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)

Comment: Your link goes to the documentation for PhoneGap 1.9. Could you update that link to a newer version, please? :)

Comment: Updated link:  [http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/index.html](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/index.html)